# JSON not returning columns in Spring Data REST / MySQL

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-rest

I am starting to build a REST API with spring data rest but the JSON object returned in my first  testing does not return the column names and just returns the links to the objects.

ENTITY:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {

private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
private String name;
private String email;

private Employee() {}

public Employee(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

REPOSITORY:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>{

}
```

REQUEST / RESPONSE:

[REQUEST / RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEON3.png)

I tried to remove the lombok @Data since I read it in a similar post but it didnt work. I´m using MySQL as database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, I solved the problems by creating getters and setter manually. If anyone knows how to be able to use Lombok please share with all:).